# Need Quartz Composer Expect - Is this possible?

Tags: movieclip, quartz-composer

Just getting started with QTZ.

Want to make sure this is possible before I jump in.

Can I have my QTZ select a random movie in a folder, run that
and then when the mov portion ends, load a static PNG
and have it hold that until the qtz unloads?

I assume each time the QTZ is loaded, it will then get the random mov
and then repeat the process.

This will be used for a station idea inside BB-TV or similar system.

So I will also need to be able to resize and move the "images" within a 720p frame size.
(i.e. display the MOV and static image in the corners)

Thanks,

Ian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to have a look at Kineme Video Tools and Data Tools at http://kineme.net/

For random loading, you can select a random index on the returned files path structure (Random -> Structure Index Member).

Then you will have to switch between your video display and your PNG display (both of them are feeding a sprite or a billboard). With Quartz Composer you can place and resize your displays as you want.